# Give each data engineer a dedicated dev environment on databricks

Tags: database, apache-spark, continuous-integration, devops, databricks

I am rather new to working with Databricks, and I come from SQL Server platform, where it is common for each developer to have a small, local development environment, where each can deploy the code, run local test and so forth.

The point in not the server being locally, it is more that developer A can deploy code from his local branch repo, and developer B can do the same, without overwriting each other code.

So the scenario I have is that there is a feature branch where two data engineers or more work together on the same feature. They each deliver part of the work, and they of course work on separate objects (that is they deliver separate views and tables).

There is one remote feature branch, and two local feature branches one for each developer.

Developer A writes code for a view, and want to test it before the code is committed to the remote branch, where will he/she test the view? Where will the "create view ...." code run, for that specific developer local branch of the feature, without interfering the work of the second developer?

This is needed for a solid CI flow, where each developer can test there own code with data before committing to the remote branch, plus the ability for devops to trigger a commit to a branch shared environment, where further tests are run to ensure that developer A commits did not break developer B work etc.

How will that work in a databricks setup? Any one who did something similar? Are there tool to enable creation of such environments?

I am aware that in databricks each developer can have its own repo with notebooks and code, but how do I manage separate catalog\schema for each developer (and for each branch)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a multiple workspaces feature available in Databricks Enterprise 2.0. This feature allows you to create separate workspaces for each developer, enabling them to work on their own code without interfering with each other

See: [Functional Workspace Organization on Databricks](https://www.databricks.com/blog/2022/03/10/functional-workspace-organization-on-databricks.html)

As for managing separate catalogs or schemas for each developer, you can create separate databases within a workspace and grant each developer access to their own database. This way, each developer can work on their own set of tables and views without interfering with each other.

Comment: Hi Paul, thanks for you answer.

The feature of functinal workspace, it being an higher level then the catalog, will allow each develolper to spin separate cluster, accessing a table with the same name, schema and catalog, but a different instance of that table?

Comment: Sorry, don't follow that question. If they are workng in their own database then they are working on their own objects in that database. Isn't that what you originally asked for ?

Comment: my point is, in sql server for instance, there are 4 levels to work with:
- server
- database
- schema
- object (e.g. table name)

say the code is 

select *
from myDatabase.mySchema.myTable;

and say each developer have their own sql server instance, then the code can run as is, for each developer.

In databricks we have:
- workspace (equivalent to server???)
- catalog (equivalent to database)
- schema
- object (e.g. table name)

is it correct to say that workspace is the 4th level like server is for sql server?

Comment: Workspace is not really analgous to server, but Catalog is analogous to Database in MSSQL. Catalogs provide a way to organize and manage your data and code in Databricks. Schema and Object have the same meaning in both MSSQL and Databricks.